# libopencc1 in bad state

Tags: debian, gnome-shell

My debian 8 is broken. I this message

[image]

It seems that libopencc1 is broken and gnome-shell does not work anymore. I tried reinstalling, removing, purging it and it won't work. I also tried sudo apt-get -f install, sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and nothing fixes the issue. I tried installing kde-standard but this did not work either because of the package.

At last I tried force purging it and it did not work either.
[image]

Can this be fixed in some other way or is a reinstall of debian a must?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq libopencc1
```

should help to get rid of this brocken package.

Comment: sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libopencc1 got the job done. Thanks!

Comment: Note the caveat in the `dpkg` manpage: "This may, for example, cause parts of the package to remain on the system, which will then be forgotten by dpkg." You should really re-install it; `--force-remove-reinstreq` is a last resort.

Comment: Right, it is a grenade, but if `apt-get -f install`is not working most `apt-get install  --reinstall` either do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall the package, without removing it:

```
apt-get --reinstall install libopencc1
```